# Build a paginated tree in SQL Server with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, treeview

Let's say I have a tree of companies and I need to list the products that each one of them has in their building, like this:

```
Owner
  Acessories
    Keyboard
    Mouse
  Furnitues
    Chair
    Table
  Company A
    Acessories
        Microfone
  Company B
    Company BB
        Others
            Blabla
```

For that, I have two tables:

```
declare @companies as table (id int, name varchar(max), parentID int)
insert into @companies
select 1, 'Owner',      null  union
select 2, 'Company A',  1     union
select 3, 'Company B',  1     union
select 4, 'Company BB', 3

declare @companiesProducts as table (id int, companyID int, category varchar(max), product varchar(max))
insert into @companiesProducts
select 1, 1, 'Acessories', 'Keyboard'  union
select 2, 1, 'Acessories', 'Mouse'     union
select 3, 1, 'Furnitues',  'Chair'     union 
select 4, 1, 'Furnitues',  'Table'     union
select 5, 2, 'Acessories', 'Microfone' union
select 6, 4, 'Others',     'Blabla'
```

I have a script to build a company tree that works fine:

```
declare @companyID int = 1
;with Hierarchy (id, parentID, level, name) as
(
   select 
      distinct A.id, A.parentID, 0 as level, A.name
   from @companies as A
   where A.id = @companyID
   union all
   select 
      A.id, A.parentID, B.level + 1, A.name
   from @Companies as A
   inner join Hierarchy as B on A.parentID = B.id
)
select 
   distinct id, parentID, level, name
from Hierarchy
order by level, name

----------------------------------
id  parentID    level   name
1   NULL        0       Owner
2   1           1       Company A
3   1           1       Company B
4   3           2       CompanyBB
```

Is there any way to build the structure with categories and products in the same script?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the problem. You already have your tree-like structure from your recursive CTE, so each level should be built out.

Can't you just join to the `@companiesProducts` table to your recursive CTE's results to get the correlating products and categories in the same tree-like structure? For example:

```
declare @companyID int = 1
;with Hierarchy (id, parentID, level, name) as
(
   select 
      distinct A.id, A.parentID, 0 as level, A.name
   from @companies as A
   where A.id = @companyID
   union all
   select 
      A.id, A.parentID, B.level + 1, A.name
   from @Companies as A
   inner join Hierarchy as B on A.parentID = B.id
),
_CompanyTree AS
(
    select 
       distinct id, parentID, level, name
    from Hierarchy
)

SELECT 
    CT.id, CT.parentID, CT.level, CT.name,
    P.category, P.product
FROM _CompanyTree AS CT
LEFT JOIN @companiesProducts AS P -- Outer join because not all Companies have Products
    ON CT.id = P.companyID
ORDER BY CT.level, CT.name, P.Product
```